# Getting Web Application Name in a Servlet

Tags: web-applications, servlets

I am developing a common artifact that can be used in multiple web applications. The developers will just have to add my listener class to their web.xml. In my listener, I have a need to get the web application name that my code is running under.

Although getServletContextName() will give a name, this name is the display-name coded in web.xml. I think display-name is optional so it is not reliable. So I would like to get the actual web application name. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for looking.

Comment: and what is the actual application name if it is not the display-name?

Comment: Is it `request.getContextPath()`, you are looking for. It returns the name of the web application which you use to invoke. e.g. http://localhost:8080/test`. So, return value will be "test"

Answer (score 4):

try with this code

```
String ApplicationName = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getContextPath()
                    .replace("/", "");
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to do this....

```
new java.io.File(context.getRealPath("/")).getName()
```

The above gives the web app name i.e WAR name.

Hardik, Thanks for looking into this.

MaVRoSCy, The display-name can be anything. It doesn't have to be the web application name. For instance, all Maven web projects will have the default display-name as 'Archetype created web application' which I don't want to pick up.

Comment: This is not a reliable way. `getRealPath()` returns `null` when the WAR file is not expanded on local disk file system, but instead in memory. This is a server-specific configuration setting and not controllable from inside your webapp.